# specify soundcard with python-gstreamer

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer

Can I please have advice on how to specify a soundcard for output in a gstreamer pipeline using python-gstreamer (pygst).

On a linux system I have provided names for the soundcards in /etc/asound.conf and testing from the command line succeeds with 'aplay -D cardname0'

I had hoped that gstreamer would be the best way to provide audio output for software I am writing in python but I need to be able to select which soundcard to use for output.

What I have tried when creating a pipeline is:

```
    self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
    fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink") 
    alsa_card0 = gst.element_factory_make("alsasink", "cardname0")
    self.player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
    self.player.set_property("audio-sink", alsa_card0)
```

However I have found that the name "cardname0" has nothing to do with the properties of the sound card, it is just a meaningless string.  Looking through the pygst documentation I can't find a way to define the alsasink so that it uses something other than the alsa default card. I could not find any documentation on other types of audio sink that could be used. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're naming an `alsasink` element `cardname0`, which indeed doesn't make a difference to the sink.
Instead, you want to set the [`device`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-alsasink.html#GstAlsaSink--device) property of the sink to `cardname0`.

eg.

```
alsa_card0.set_property("device", "cardname0")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that does look like what I need. I won't be able to test it for a couple of days until I get back to the test computer.

Comment: Look at `gst-inspect <element-name>` to get a list of properties. And you could use `gst_property_probe` to get a list of sound devices (can't give you any further details, I only used it in C code and don't know how it works in .py)